# passing variables from PHP page to jQuery modal window

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery

Ok, so as the title implies, I'm opening a modal dialog and need to pass it various variables, one of which is the url of the page I'm starting from. Now this wouldn't be a problem if the jQuery that creates the dialog was in script tags in the head of a page as I could use PHP to echo the info and append it to the URL as a GET string, but the code is actually in an external .js file which is referenced in the head.

script.js:

```
var dialogVariables = {
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 500,
    buttons: { 
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        } //end cancel button
    },//end button
    open: function() {
        $("#reportDialog").load("/report.php");}
    };
$("#reportDialog").dialog(dialogVariables);
```

Any ideas as to how I can pass the information across?

Answer (score 1):

Output the data into hidden form fields. Use the values in those form fields to construct the url.

Comment: the whole idea of having the content loaded by ajax rather than stored in an inline div with display:none was to avoid this, is it not possible to pick up these values from within report.php in the modal window?

edit: as I don't have access to the URL (it's effectively hard-coded in script.js), surely I'm not able to alter it?

Comment: Can you pass a script in report.php? Using jquery load will execute any scripts contained in the loaded file, and those scripts will have access to the complete DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I would add some data attribute to the element like for example:

```
<div id="reportDialog" data-varname="some data"></div>
```

You can get this using:

```
$('#reportDialog').data('varname');
```

Comment: Hmm, that might just work. I'm too tired tonight though, that'll be a job for tomorrow I think